# How do I avoid a dark subject when there's bright sunlight from windows?

Tags: metering, dynamic-range, sunlight, darkness, backlight

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you avoid a dim portrait with a bright background and no external flash?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5781/how-do-you-avoid-a-dim-portrait-with-a-bright-background-and-no-external-flash)

I recently shot some photos at a friend's wedding. The location was lovely with lots of light — sometimes too much. The sunlight from the windows and skylights seemed to overpower the shot and the subject/people were very dark. What are some ways to avoid this without using fancy equipment? (I'm just starting out, I'm not a wedding photographer or anything!)

Here is one example I took — and this is *after* I've lightened it somewhat with Picasa:

[image: example]

I'm using a Nikon D5000 with a standard 18-55mm lens.